# How to get a substring using strchr in multiple occurrences of '/' in c and store it in a variable

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    char buf[50] = "user/local/etc/bin/example.txt";
    char* ptr;
    ptr = strchr(buf, '/');
    char path[20];
    strncpy(path, buf, ptr-buf);
    path[ptr-buf] =0;
    printf("%s\n", path);
    return 0;
}
```

I am able the get the substring before the first occurence of '/' i.e. I can get `user` but how can I get the substring after the second occurrence of '/' i.e. `local` and also the last occurence of '/' i.e. `example` without the extension .txt? How can it be done efficiently

Comment: The substring after the second slash looks more like `etc` than `local` given that there isn't a leading `/`.  `strrchr()` could be used to find the last `/` and the last `.`.  For the second substring, `char *s1 = strchar(buf, '/'); char *s2 = strchar(s1+1, '/');` would give you the start in `s2` — if you need to find the end, you can use `char *s3 = strchr(s2 + 1, '/');`.  You need to worry about null returned pointers in case what you're looking for isn't present. You might also care to think about what should happen with `user//local//etc//bin//example.txt` – that refers to the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `strchr` for this. The problem is that `strchr` can only find one specific character but you care about both `/` and `.` Instead I would iterate the string using a pointer and check for both characters inside the loop..

Something like:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[50] = "user/local/etc/bin/example.txt";
    char* pStart = buf;
    char* pCurrent = buf;
    while(*pCurrent != '\0')
    {
        if (*pCurrent == '/' || *pCurrent == '.') 
        {
            char str[20] = {0};
            strncpy(str, pStart, pCurrent - pStart);
            printf("%s\n", str);    
            pStart = pCurrent+1;
        }
        ++pCurrent;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
user
local
etc
bin
example
```

If you really want to do this using `strchr` it could be like:

```
int main()
{   
    char buf[50] = "user/local/etc/bin/example.txt";
    char* pStart = buf;
    char* pCurrent = strchr(pStart, '/');
    while(pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        char str[20] = {0};
        strncpy(str, pStart, pCurrent - pStart);
        printf("%s\n", str);    
        pStart = pCurrent+1;
        pCurrent = strchr(pStart, '/');
    }

    pCurrent = strchr(pStart, '.');
    if (pCurrent != NULL)
    {
        char str[20] = {0};
        strncpy(str, pStart, pCurrent - pStart);
        printf("%s\n", str);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but as you can see, it requires a bit more code than the first example.

Comment: What happens with `user/local/upper.lower/etc/example.txt` where there's a dot in one of the sub-directory names?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sure you know what will happen. You could as well ask "what happens to `user/123456789012345678901/e.txt` ?" Like many other SO answers this answer is not "production quality" code but hopefully it will help OP a step further.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtok()` in this case For detailed [description](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/) check this link ! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>   

#define MAXLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    char buf[] = "user/local/etc/bin/example.txt";
    char substring[MAXLEN+1];
    char *a, *b;
    int len;

    b = buf;                                   
    while ( (a = strchr(b, '/')) != NULL || (a = strchr(b, '.')) != NULL) 
    {
        len = a - b;                         
        if (len > MAXLEN)
            return 0;                             
        memcpy(substring, b, len);              
        substring[len] = 0;                         
        printf("'%s'\n", substring);   
        b = a + 1;                           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the ouput:

```
'user'
'local'
'etc'
'bin'
'example'
```