# Why is my acronym lookup utility surprisingly slow?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I started working on a little side project to implement a small C console program to do quick acronym searches. I work in a company/industry where there are literally 1000s of acronyms!

The acronyms were gathered (copy/pasted) from various documents and put in a single text file. The program loads the contents of this file into memory, and stores it in a linked list.

The format I used is:

**ACRONYM # Definition**

or in the case of an acronym having multiple definitions:

**ACRONYM # Definition1; Definition2; Definition3**

In general, the program works well - some basic error handling is implemented and has saved me time looking up multiple documents.

What made me curious though was the load time of the acronym list. For about *900* acronyms, it takes about *0.35 seconds* to load the list into memory and be ready to take user input.

The two key functions are:

- `char * loadACR( FILE * fptr, unsigned long int file_size )`
- `AcronymDB * mapAcroDefs( const char * filecont )`

`loadACR` loads the entire file into memory

`mapAcroDefs` calls other functions to create the acronym database, process file contents, create new definitions, iterate through the linked list, store, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "resources.h"

/*************** DEFS **********************/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

#define acro_length 16
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 3145728 //(in bytes == 3MB)
#define SET_GREEN SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY );
#define SET_RED SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY );
#define SET_CYAN SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE );
#define SET_WHITE SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE );

/******************************************/

/*************** GLOBALS *******************/
//#include <sys/time.h>
//struct timeval tv1,tv2;
/*******************************************/

/*************** STRUCTS *******************/

//associated definitions in a linked list
typedef struct defnList
{
    char * defn;
    struct defnList * next;
} Definition;

//acronym entry
typedef struct
{
    char * acronym;
    Definition * f_defn;     //a pointer to the first definition
} Acronym;

//database of acronyms
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int entries;
    Acronym ** acronyms;     //array of pointers to acronym entries
} AcronymDB;

/******************************************/

void throwError( unsigned short int err_code, AcronymDB * entry_list, unsigned int r )
{
    SET_RED
    switch ( err_code )
    {
        //retFileHandle errors
        case 1:
            puts( "Directory path error - check access rights" );
            break;
        //getFileSize errors
        case 5:
            puts( "'.acr' file is greater than 3MB, reduce the file size and try again.\n" );
            break;
        //macroAcroDefs errors
        case 35:
        case 36:
        case 37:
            printf( "Error(s) found at lines %u to %u\n", r - 1, r + 1 );
            printf( "Code: %d\n", err_code );
            break;
        //main() errors
        case 40:
            puts( "File error - ensure a '.acr' definitions file exists in the program folder." );
            break;
        //malloc errors
        default:
            printf( "Memory Allocation Error - Code: %d\n", err_code );
    }

    free( entry_list );
    puts ( "Program ended" );
    getchar();
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

void chkMalloc( void * chk_me, unsigned short int err_code, AcronymDB * entry_list )
{
    if ( !chk_me && ( sizeof ( chk_me ) > 0 ) )
    {
        throwError( err_code, entry_list, 0 );
    }
}

char * getInputAcronym()
{
    char input_acro[ acro_length ], c;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF )
    {
        if( acro_length == i || c == ' ' )
        {
            fflush( stdin );
            return ( "err_format" );
        }

        //some acronyms contain parentheses, hyphens etc, these are ignored if the user enters it
        //as they are removed in the mapAcroDefs function before adding into the list
        if ( c != '-' &&
             c != '(' &&
             c != ')' &&
             c != '&' &&
             c != '/'   )
        {
            input_acro[ i ] = toupper( c );
            i++;
        }
    }

    input_acro[ i ] = '\0';

    return strdup( input_acro );
}

FILE * retFileHandle() //errcodes 1 - 4
{
    DIR           * dptr;
    struct dirent * directory;
    FILE          * acr_file;

    dptr = opendir( "." );
    if ( dptr == NULL ) throwError( 1, NULL, 0 );

    while( ( directory = readdir( dptr ) ) != NULL )
    {
        //check whether the file name contains .acr
        //n.b: only the first found .acr occurrence will be used
        if( strstr( directory -> d_name, ".acr" ) )
        {
            acr_file = fopen( directory -> d_name , "r" );
            closedir( dptr );
            return ( acr_file );
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

unsigned long int getFileSize( FILE * fptr ) //errcodes 5 - 9
{
    unsigned long int file_size, prev;

    prev = ftell( fptr );
    fseek( fptr, 0, SEEK_END );
    file_size = ftell( fptr );
    fseek( fptr, prev, SEEK_SET );

    // > 3MB
    if( file_size >= MAX_FILE_SIZE ) throwError( 5, NULL, 0 );

    else
    {
        return ( file_size );
    }

    return 0; // should never get here, but the compiler complains of returning non-void
}

//load the acr file into memory
char * loadACR( FILE * fptr, unsigned long int file_size ) //errcodes 10 - 14
{
    char * read_buffer;

    read_buffer = ( char * ) malloc ( file_size );
    chkMalloc( read_buffer, 10, NULL );

    //fread returns the total number of elements, so set that last element to '\0' to remove random characters at the end
    read_buffer[ fread( read_buffer, 1, file_size, fptr ) ] = '\0';

    return ( read_buffer );
}

unsigned int countRows( const char * filecont )
{
    unsigned int rows = 0, i;

    for ( i = 0; i < strlen( filecont ); i++ )
    {
        //disregard blank lines at the top or somewhere in the middle
        if ( ( '\n' == filecont[ i ] ) && ( 0 != i ) && ( '\n' != filecont[ i + 1 ] ) )
        {
            rows++;
        }
    }
    //if there's a new line at the end, disregard
    if ( ( '\0' == filecont[ i ] ) && ( '\n' == filecont[ i - 1 ] ) ) rows--;

    return ( rows );
}

void remPunct( char * delimbuff )
{
    char * src, * dst;

    for ( src = dst = delimbuff; * src != '\0'; src++ )
    {
        * dst = * src;
        if ( * dst != '-' &&
             * dst != '(' &&
             * dst != ')' &&
             * dst != '&' &&
             * dst != '/'   )
        {
            dst++;
        }
    }

    * dst = '\0';
}

void addAcronym( AcronymDB * entry_list, char * delimbuff, unsigned int r ) //errcodes 15 - 19
{

    char * ptr_delim;
    //convert the characters to uppercase to make matching easier later, some acronyms have a mix of upper and lowercase
    for ( ptr_delim = delimbuff; * ptr_delim != '\0'; ptr_delim++ )
    {
        * ptr_delim = toupper( * ptr_delim );
    }

    entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] = malloc( sizeof( Acronym ) );
    chkMalloc( entry_list -> acronyms[ r ], 15, entry_list );

    entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> acronym = strdup( delimbuff );
    chkMalloc( entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> acronym, 16, entry_list );
}

Definition * initDefn() //errcodes 20 - 24
{
    Definition * newDefn = malloc( sizeof( Definition ) );
    chkMalloc( newDefn, 20, NULL );

    newDefn = NULL;
    return ( newDefn );
}

Definition * addDefn( AcronymDB * entry_list, Definition * newDefn, char * delimbuff, unsigned int r ) //errcodes 25 - 29
{

    Definition * head = newDefn;
    Definition * currDefn;
    //first entry if head is NULL, allocate space for the first definition and store it
    if ( NULL == head )
    {
        head = entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn = malloc( sizeof( Definition ) );
        chkMalloc( entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn, 25, entry_list );

        entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn -> defn = strdup( delimbuff );
        chkMalloc( entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn -> defn, 26, entry_list );

        head -> next = entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn -> next = NULL;

        return ( head );
    }
    //else go through all the existing definitions and put the definition at the end of the list
    currDefn = entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> f_defn;

    while ( NULL != currDefn -> next )
    {
        currDefn = currDefn -> next;
    }

    currDefn -> next = malloc ( sizeof( Definition ) );
    chkMalloc( currDefn -> next, 27, entry_list );
    currDefn = currDefn -> next;

    currDefn -> defn = strdup( delimbuff );
    chkMalloc( currDefn -> defn, 28, entry_list );

    currDefn -> next = NULL;

    return ( head );
}

//create space for the database of acronyms and enough space for the entry list based on rows counted earlier
AcronymDB * initAcroDB( unsigned int rows ) //errcodes 30 - 34
{
    AcronymDB * entry_list = malloc( sizeof( AcronymDB ) );
    chkMalloc( entry_list, 30, 0 );

    entry_list -> acronyms = malloc( sizeof( Acronym * ) * rows );
    chkMalloc( entry_list -> acronyms, 31, entry_list );

    entry_list -> entries = rows;

    return ( entry_list );
}

Definition * procMultiDefs( const char * pStart, const char * pCurrent, AcronymDB * entry_list, Definition * newDefn, unsigned int r  )
{
    //i hope 250 characters is enough? :S
    char tmpdefhold[ 250 ] = { 0 };

    //we don't want to memmove here as it will affect pCurrent as well, just change where pStart is pointing
    if ( ' ' == pStart[ 0 ] ) ++pStart;

    strncpy( tmpdefhold, pStart, pCurrent - pStart );
    newDefn = addDefn( entry_list, newDefn, tmpdefhold, r );

    return ( newDefn );
}

AcronymDB * mapAcroDefs( const char * filecont ) //errcodes 35 - 39
{
    SET_CYAN  printf( "Acronym Search v1.1\n" );
    SET_WHITE printf( "Reading acronym list...\n" );

    unsigned int rows = countRows( filecont ), r = 0;
    char * tmp_filecont, * delimbuff;

    //copy contents of file into a temporary buffer so it can be passed to strtok
    tmp_filecont = ( char * ) malloc ( ( strlen( filecont ) + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    if ( NULL == tmp_filecont ) throwError( 30, NULL, 0 );

    strncpy( tmp_filecont, filecont, strlen( filecont ) + 1 ); //create a temporary string and null terminate it
    tmp_filecont[ strlen( tmp_filecont ) ] = '\0';

    //create space for database of acronyms based on entries counted
    AcronymDB * entry_list = initAcroDB( rows );

    //tokenise the file contents, the first split will be an acronym entry including a space before the hash
    delimbuff = strtok( tmp_filecont, "#\n" );

    while ( r <= rows )
    {   //catch potential errors in the file (not tokenised according to # or \n
        if ( NULL == delimbuff )
        {
            free( tmp_filecont );
            throwError( 35, entry_list, r + 1 );
        }
        //return location of space before the hash
        char * spcptr = strchr( delimbuff, ' ' );
        if ( NULL == spcptr )
        {
            free( tmp_filecont );
            throwError( 36, entry_list, r + 1 );
        }
        //terminate the word correctly, hopefully we have a valid acronym entry now
        * spcptr = '\0';

        remPunct( delimbuff );
        addAcronym( entry_list, delimbuff, r );

        //allocate memory for a new definition
        Definition * newDefn = initDefn();

        while ( NULL != delimbuff )
        {
            delimbuff = strtok( NULL, "#\n" );

            //get rid of the space that will be present, otherwise there's a formatting error present, missing hash/other char
            if ( ' ' == delimbuff[ 0 ] ) memmove( delimbuff, delimbuff + 1, strlen( delimbuff ) );

            //multiple definitions exist
            if ( NULL != strstr( delimbuff, ";" ) )
            {
                char * pStart = delimbuff, * pCurrent = delimbuff;

                //go through the entire string and process the multiple definitions
                //two pointers are used to mark the string from <start to ';'>
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788179/how-to-get-a-substring-using-strchr-in-multiple-occurrences-of-in-c-and-stor
                while ( '\0' != * pCurrent)
                {
                    if ( ';' == * pCurrent )
                    {
                        newDefn = procMultiDefs( pStart, pCurrent, entry_list, newDefn, r );
                        pStart = pCurrent + 1;
                    }
                    ++pCurrent;
                }
                //last definition after ; wouldn't be captured by the loop above, so do this again immediately after
                newDefn = procMultiDefs( pStart, pCurrent, entry_list, newDefn, r );
            }
            else
            {
                newDefn = addDefn( entry_list, newDefn, delimbuff, r );
            }
            //go to the next line now
            if ( NULL == strstr( delimbuff, "\n" ) )
            {
                r++;
                delimbuff = strtok( NULL, "#\n" );
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    free( tmp_filecont );
    return ( entry_list );
}

//start from the beginning of the acronym list and look for a match, print any associated definitions
int lookUpAcro( AcronymDB * entry_list, const char * retstring )
{
    unsigned int b = 0;
    int found = -1;

    Acronym * currAcro = entry_list -> acronyms[ b ];

    while ( b <= entry_list -> entries )
    {
        if ( 0 == strcmp( currAcro -> acronym, retstring ) )
        {
            Definition * currDefn = entry_list -> acronyms[ b ] -> f_defn;

            while ( NULL != currDefn )
            {
                SET_GREEN
                SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 ); //this is required to print out UTF-8 characters, but doesn't work properly?
                printf( "   %s\n", currDefn -> defn );
                currDefn = currDefn -> next;
            }
            SET_WHITE
            found = 1;
            //in case there are duplicate acronym entries with different definitions
            currAcro = entry_list -> acronyms[ ++b ];
        }
        else
        {
            currAcro = entry_list -> acronyms[ ++b ];
        }

    }
    return ( found );
}

int main () //errcodes 40 - 50
{
    char  * retstring, * filecont;
    FILE  * fptr;
    unsigned long int file_size = 0;
    AcronymDB * entry_list;

    system( "Acronym Search" );
    //gettimeofday( &tv1, NULL );

    //open definitions file
    if( ( fptr = retFileHandle() ) == NULL ) throwError( 40, NULL, 0 );

    file_size = getFileSize( fptr );
    filecont = loadACR( fptr, file_size );
    fclose( fptr );

    //create linked lists of acronyms and defs from the file contents read in above, then free the temporary read buffer; filecont
    entry_list = mapAcroDefs( filecont );
    printf( "%u acronyms loaded\n\n", entry_list -> entries + 1 );
    free( filecont );

//  gettimeofday( &tv2, NULL );
//  printf ("Total time = %f seconds\n",
//           ( double ) ( tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec ) / 1000000 +
//           ( double ) ( tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec ) );

    while ( NULL != entry_list )
    {
        //get input acronym, string is NULL terminated within function
        retstring = getInputAcronym();

        if( 0 == strcmp( retstring, "err_format" ) )
        {
            free( retstring );

            SET_RED printf( "Input format error - try again: \n  1) Maximum word length is 15 characters \n  2) No spaces. \n\n" ); SET_WHITE
            continue;
        }                       //multiple ways to exit
        else if( 0 == strcmp( retstring, "." )  || 0 == strcmp( retstring, ".." ) ||
                 0 == strcmp( retstring, ",," ) || 0 == strcmp( retstring, ",." ) ||
                 0 == strcmp( retstring, ".," ) || 0 == strcmp( retstring, "," ) )
        {
            break;
        }

        if ( -1 == lookUpAcro( entry_list, retstring ) )  { SET_RED printf( "Acronym '%s' not found\n\n", retstring ); SET_WHITE }

        free( retstring );
    }

    printf( "Program ended\n" );

    free( retstring );
    free( entry_list );

    return 0;
}
```

I just copy pasted my existing list many times to see how long it takes to load:

**Acronyms - Seconds**

- 1,640 - 0.91 s (1800 acronyms/second)
- 3,280 - 3.64 s
- 6,560 - 14.27 s
- 13,120 - 57.30 s (229 acronyms/second)
- 26,240 - 231.75 s
- 52,480 ~ 927 s
- 104,960 ~ 3708 s
- 209,920 - 14083 s (15 acronyms/second)

For the last one, I left it running overnight.

Realistically, I think there'd be *5000* acronyms at the very most, and even that's unlikely - but I am just interested to see if there's a way to improve this load time. Perhaps use a different data structure?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This line `read_buffer[ fread( read_buffer, 1, file_size, fptr ) ] = '\0';` writes outside the allocated memory.

Comment: Is the data in sorted order?  Would sorting the data help?  Do you have to search the entire list to find that the acronym isn't there?  Is a linked list the correct structure to be using (hash table, perhaps)?

Comment: This line `for ( i = 0; i < strlen( filecont ); i++ )` can be a performance disaster, especially on big files.  Each iteration of the loop has to calculate the length of the entire string, even though it didn't change.  Move the `strlen()` out of the loop.  (Which compilation options did you use?)  This is in 
`unsigned int countRows( const char * filecont )`.

Comment: @TomWojcik - done, I removed the unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Hmmm; you removed a line I regard as crucial to your slow performance (probably).  I've rolled back your too dramatic change.

Comment: Scanning your entire list to find the end each time you want to add a new definition is an extremely bad algorithm choice.  It turns an O(n) algorithm into an O(n**2) algorithm.  It's not something an experienced engineer would ever do.  To fix, you can (1) always add to the front of the list, (2) keep a pointer to the end of the list, or (3) use a doubly-linked list, giving immediate access to both ends.  Even using a dynamically allocated array in place of the linked list would be faster (if you double the length each time you need to grow it to limit the amount of copying needed).

Comment: There's a theory that says "if you have working code and want improvements, you should ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)".  It would be an alternative venue, for sure.  It might be better than SO, though not necessarily as fast in the feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jonathan Leffler, apologies about posting this in the wrong place. I wasn't aware of that area of SO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Excellent spot with the strlen in the for loop, don't know how I didn't see that!! I am using Eclipse, and it is using default build options I think, as I didn't modify them: gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0

Comment: It's not a major issue — we can argue that the performance issues are a bug and leave it here on SO.

Comment: Using `-O0` means that there is no optimization.  That `strlen()` in the `for` loop becomes a major problem — and the bigger the file, the worse the problem (quadratic behaviour).  With optimization, the compiler might deduce that it can call `strlen()` once, but with `-O0`, not a chance!  I only use `-O0` if I'm going to have to run the debugger on the program — and I don't use a debugger all that often (I tend to use printing statements instead).

Comment: C style: you have `entry_list -> acronyms[ r ] -> acronym = strdup( delimbuff );` — don't put spaces around the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.  They bind very tightly and should not have spaces around them.

Comment: In `chkMalloc()`, you have `if ( !chk_me && ( sizeof ( chk_me ) > 0 ) )` — the size of `chk_me` is always the same, and it is the size of a `void *`; the `&&` part is pointless.

Comment: I just fixed the ````strlen()```` issue in the code, and guess what? 0.35 seconds to load 209,920 acronyms. I feel a bit daft now.

Comment: In `throwError()`, you have `free(entry_list)`; that does not free everything that's allocated.  You need a function that chases through the list, releasing data as it goes.  Also, error messages should be written to standard error (`stderr`) and not standard output.

Comment: You probably can still improve the performance — it is not clear that you need to do so.  Yes, that sort of quadratic behaviour really hurts when you are continually scanning 4 MiB or more of data (4 MiB = 200K rows * 20 bytes per row).

Comment: The best way to improve **list** performance is to **not use a linked list at all!**. Use an array with `realloc`. It will always be faster than your linked list. See this one from [Bjarne Stroustrup in C++ but which equally does apply to C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=19&v=YQs6IC-vgmo)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - appreciate the helpful hints. I will actually start making these changes. It's been many years since I did any C programming and fixing these issues should help in the future. Although, if I free ````entry_list```` shouldn't all its members also be freed? Are you saying I need to loop through all members and free them?

Comment: Yes, you need a function that iterates over all the members of the list, freeing them.  If you're on a platform where it works, use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to track down memory leaks (unfreed memory).

Comment: I'm 2+ hours late for bed; I may write up an answer later today (8+ hours later) if there isn't an answer hitting on the key cost already.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I shall mark your answer as the correct one Jonathan Leffler, I think everyone has given good advice, but that ````strlen```` issue was the big one. Very good pickup in a lot of nonsense code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I saw this video a week ago when I was looking at how to solve my linked list speed problems. Although, there will not be much gain now to re-write all of this. For my next project, certainly.

Comment: Though 4386427's answer will get you a drastic performance insert in any case. But yes, linked lists are vastly overrrated. They're only ever useful when you need to have `O(1)` access lists of structures for which the memory is already allocated and the nodes themselves hold the link pointers.

Comment: `char  c; ... c = getchar()` --> use `int c` instead  to store the 257 different results.

Comment: I'm sure that https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more suitable place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timings clearly indicate a quadratic time complexity, **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**: it takes 4 times longer to handle twice the input size.

There are multiple occurrences of quadratic algorithms:

- in function `count_rows`, you use a classic but drastically inefficient method:

  ```
  for ( i = 0; i < strlen( filecont ); i++ )
  ```

  You should avoid recomputing the input length at each iteration with:

  ```
  for ( i = 0; filecont[i] != '\0'; i++ )
  ```
- in `addDefn`, you iterate over the existing list for a given acronym to add the definition at the end of the list. You should instead either keep a pointer to the last node of the list, or insert the new definition at the beginning, giving precedence to later acronym definitions. Anyway, these lists are very small because they are alternate definitions for the same acronym, so this really should not be an issue.

There are other problems:

- the file contents should be allocated with an extra byte for the null terminator
- `c` must be defined as an `int` for the value `EOF` returned by `getchar()` to be handled correctly.
- `strncpy()` is a false friend: if the string does not fit in the destination array, the copied portion is not null terminated, and if it fits, the rest of the array is set to '\0', which is inefficient. Use `strcpy` or even `memcpy` if you know the string length and the destination array is allocated to the proper size.
- `fflush( stdin );` has undefined behavior. It may discard pending input on some architectures, but it is not a portable way to do this.

I did some testing on OS/X: clang is able to optimise the repeated calls to `strlen()` out of the loop, so the program loads a list of 5000 acronyms in **0.023s** when compiled with `-O3` vs **2.969s** in unoptimized `-O0` mode.  Removing the `strlen()` call brings the unoptimized build down to 0.016s, and the optimized build to **0.012s**. This was obviously **the** bottleneck in your program.

Comment: Appreciate the detail and insight!

Answer (score 4):

The `addDefn` functions adds to the end of the list using a `while` loop to reach the end. This is very inefficient, i.e. O(n) for insert.

You can do one of two things:

1) As the list isn't sorted, you can add to the head of the list

or

2) Have a tail pointer so that you know where to insert the next element.

This will give you O(1) insert instead of the current O(n)

Comment: Your last line should emphasize that each insert becomes O(1) instead of O(N), so the overall cost goes from O(N²) to O(N).  I'm not sure it's the only place there's O(N²) performance — see my comment about `unsigned int countRows( const char * filecont )` and the `for` loop with `strlen()` in it.

Comment: Good catch, but the real problem is here: `for ( i = 0; i < strlen( filecont ); i++ )`